# React app not Building shows code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router

This error is shown whenever i try to build the project. Can someone please help me with this

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! covid-19-world@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the covid-19-world@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\uniqf\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-02T16_41_30_577Z-debug.log
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command npm run build" terminated with exit code: 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following -

- Delete the `node_modules` folder
- Delete the `package-lock.json` if it exists
- run `npm install` in the terminal

Comment: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined <<<<<<<<THis error is shown

Comment: looks like it is a compile error. have you checked your css file for any syntax error?

Comment: just to confirm which node version are you using? and are you using the `create-react-app`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found the problem and solved it by removing the cache, Doing what SFUE said above and created a new project with all the source code of earlier and I was able to build the project